# Pick values from N number of list in nested dictionary

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read response from REST API and put it into csv file.
I have written code for the response as below:

**Response :**

```
data ={
        "status":
        {
            "type":"A",
            "code":"200",
            "severity":"11",
            "message":"",
            "correlationId":""   
        }

        ,

    "Data":{
            "Id":"11",
            "LineNo":"2",
            "requestedAmt":"100",
            "ReceivedDt":"",
            "FromDt":"",
            "ToDate":"",
            "Status":"N"
        }
    }
```

***Code***

```
result =[]    

with open('try.csv','w') as f:
    for rowo in data:
        for rowin in data[rowo]:
            result.append((data[rowo][rowin]))

    f.write(','.join(result)+"\n")
```

but what if the response is the nested one. There could be multiple response. In this case, I need to pick values from list technically. But, how can I loop through N Number of list and pick the values from it.

**`Response :`**

```
data ={
        "status":[
        {
            "type":"A",
            "code":"200",
            "severity":"11",
            "message":"",
            "correlationId":""   
        },
        {
            "type":"A",
            "code":"100",
            "severity":"13",
            "message":"",
            "correlationId":""   
        }
    ] #there could be more in same way,

    "Data":[
        {
            "Id":"11",
            "LineNo":"2",
            "requestedAmt":"100",
            "ReceivedDt":"",
            "FromDt":"",
            "ToDate":"",
            "Status":"N"
        },
            "Id":"13",
            "LineNo":"3",
            "requestedAmt":"100",
            "ReceivedDt":"",
            "FromDt":"",
            "ToDate":"",
            "Status":"F"
    ]
} #there could be more in same way
```

Comment: Will N always be the same across the responses? i.e. if `status` have 10 items, the rest of the `Data` and any anticipated items in the main data key will also contain a `list` of 10 items? I guess the key question is how do you expect to flatten the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a consistent `list` length between each main key in the `json` response, you can flatten the separated `list`s of `dict`s into one cohesive `list` first:

```
flat_data = [{k:v for j in i for k, v in j.items()} for i in zip(*[data[key] for key in data])]

flat_data
# [{'FromDt': '', 'Id': '11', 'LineNo': '2', 'ReceivedDt': '', 'Status': 'N', 'ToDate': '', 'code': '200', 'correlationId': '', 'message': '', 'requestedAmt': '100', 'severity': '11', 'type': 'A'},
#   'FromDt': '', 'Id': '13', 'LineNo': '3', 'ReceivedDt': '', 'Status': 'F', 'ToDate': '', 'code': '100', 'correlationId': '', 'message': '', 'requestedAmt': '100', 'severity': '13', 'type': 'A'}]
```

The `zip()` function is especially useful in this case as it essentially allows you create a `list` of the keys while you loop through N, i.e each N will return a tuple of `(data['status'], data['Data'], ...)` at which point all you need to do is flatten the tuple into one cohesive `dict` for the list.  In this particular case, we can combine the list comprehension and dict comprehension to achieve this purpose.

Once you have the flattened data, you can write this `list` of `dict`s to the `csv` however you want.  You might consider using `csv.DictWriter` since you already have it in `dict` format:

```
from csv import DictWriter
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    csvwriter = DictWriter(f, flat_data[0].keys(), lineterminator='\n')
    csvwriter.writeheader()
    csvwriter.writerows(flat_data)
```

The resulting file:

```
type    code    severity    message correlationId   Id  LineNo  requestedAmt    ReceivedDt  FromDt  ToDate  Status
A       200     11                                  11      2   100                                         N
A       100     13                                  13      3   100                                         F
```

**Note:** If the assumption of consistent length is incorrect though, this won't work as you will need to consider how the data should look like when it encounters an inconsistent row.  At which point, additional criteria will be required to update this code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your response is JSON format, so try

```
import json
x = json.load('your_response')


data = open('your_response.csv', 'w')
csvwriter = csv.writer(data)

count = 0
for i in x:
  if count == 0:
         header = i.keys()
         csvwriter.writerow(header)
         count += 1
  csvwriter.writerow(i.values())

data.close()
```

Comment: `for i in data:` is gonna give you some trouble there.

Comment: can you explain what the issue might be?

Comment: Your `data` is an opened file stream with write access only, you won't be able to iterate through it (no read access).  Also it doesn't make much sense to iterate through a file you intend to write (you probably meant to iterate through the response?).

Comment: Consider adding a `with` block around the file I/O

Comment: Oh darn it, I meant to iterate over the `data`

Comment: Have you tested your code? Because I don't think it works the way you think it would.  e.g. `i.values()` is gonna throw you an error already.  Also it doesn't address OP's question on handling the `list`.